# How do i check out from code.google

Tags: google-code

The source is located [on Google project](https://somewhere.googlecode.com/hg/). It's a .net project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/). Mercurial is a distributed revision control tool.

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting is wonky, but you answered your own question.  To check out a project that's in Mercurial, you type

```
hg clone https://somewhere.googlecode.com/hg/ somewhere
```

at the command line.  This expects that you have [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org) installed and it is on the executable path.